# how to delete a remote tag in git, when there is ambiguity in name with branch name

Tags: git

how to delete a remote tag in git, when there is ambiguity in name with branch name

```
$ git push origin :refs/tags/<tag name>
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/xxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa':
remote: Branch refs/tags/<tag name>:
remote: You need 'Push' rights with the 'Force Push'
remote: flag set to delete references.
remote: User: xxxxxxx
remote: Please read the documentation and contact an administrator
remote: if you feel the configuration is incorrect
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
To ssh://xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] <tag name> (cannot delete references)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.git'
```

Please help me in this regard. Here the tag name which I want to delete is same as one of the branches which I want keep.

Comment: You did everything correctly. The `refs/tags/` prefix should disambiguate the name. The real issue here is the one described in poke's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The remote repository prevents you from removing references. It says so in the error message: *“You need 'Push' rights with the 'Force Push' flag set to delete references.”*.

Git’s tags are references too, just like, that’s why there is no difference to them when pushing or deleting them on the remote.

Comment: I had created `origin/origin/release/v1.0.0-rc1.` by accident and using the force flag as suggested did indeed help: `git push -f origin --delete origin/release/v1.0.0-rc1` otherwise I also kept running into `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/release/v1.0.0-rc1..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`